# Twitter: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, twitter

I want to analyze twitter data (JSON file) using python, here is the script:

```
import json
fname = 'analisis.json' with open(fname, 'r') as f:

users_with_geodata = {
    "data": []
}
all_users = []
total_tweets = 0
geo_tweets  = 0
for line in f:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    if tweet['user']['id']:
        total_tweets += 1 
        user_id = tweet['user']['id']
        if user_id not in all_users:
            all_users.append(user_id)

            #Give users some data to find them by. User_id listed separately 
            # to make iterating this data later easier
            user_data = {
                "user_id" : tweet['user']['id'],
                "features" : {
                    "name" : tweet['user']['name'],
                    "id": tweet['user']['id'],
                    "screen_name": tweet['user']['screen_name'],
                    "tweets" : 1,
                    "location": tweet['user']['location'],
                }
            }
            #Iterate through different types of geodata to get the variable primary_geo
            if tweet['coordinates']:
                user_data["features"]["primary_geo"] = str(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates'].keys()[1]][1]) + ", " + str(tweet['coordinates'][tweet['coordinates'].keys()[1]][0])
                user_data["features"]["geo_type"] = "Tweet coordinates"
            elif tweet['place']:
                user_data["features"]["primary_geo"] = tweet['place']['full_name'] + ", " + tweet['place']['country']
                user_data["features"]["geo_type"] = "Tweet place"
            else:
                user_data["features"]["primary_geo"] = tweet['user']['location']
                user_data["features"]["geo_type"] = "User location"
            #Add only tweets with some geo data to .json. Comment this if you want to include all tweets.
            if user_data["features"]["primary_geo"]:
                users_with_geodata['data'].append(user_data)
                geo_tweets += 1

        #If user already listed, increase their tweet count
        elif user_id in all_users:
            for user in users_with_geodata["data"]:
                if user_id == user["user_id"]:
                    user["features"]["tweets"] += 1

#Count the total amount of tweets for those users that had geodata            
for user in users_with_geodata["data"]:
    geo_tweets = geo_tweets + user["features"]["tweets"]
#Get some aggregated numbers on the data
print ("The file included ") + str(len(all_users)) + (" unique users who tweeted with or without geo data")
print ("The file included ") + str(len(users_with_geodata['data'])) + (" unique users who tweeted with geo data, including 'location'")
print ("The users with geo data tweeted ") + str(geo_tweets) + (" out of the total ") + str(total_tweets) + (" of tweets.")

with open('analisis_geo.json', 'w') as fout:
fout.write(json.dumps(users_with_geodata, indent=4))
```

when I run in python 3.6.1, there is error message:
[image: python 3.6.1] 
. But in python 2.7.13 the script can running well, like this:
[image: python 2.7.13]
. Does anyone know how to make the script compatible with python 3.6.1?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 `dict.keys()` returns a different type of object. In order to access a key by index you'll need to cast it as a `list`. So

`keys = list(my_dict.keys())[0]`

You can also iterate through the keys as you would in a `for` loop, which doesn't really help you here, though.

```
for key in my_dict.keys():
    # do things
```

Comment: Can you show me what part of script I have to edit?

I'm sorry, because I don't know about Python, I got the script from internet.